# High CPU from httpd process

Tags: httpd, high-load, debug

I am currently getting high CPU on a server that is just running a couple of sites with very low traffic. One of the sites is in still development going live soon. However, this site is very very slow...When browsing through its pages I can see that the CPU goes from 30% to 100% for httpd (see top output below).

I have tuned httpd & MySQL, Apache Solr, Tomcat for high performance, and I am using APC.

Not sure what to do from here or how to find the culprit as I have a bunch of messages on the httpd log and have been chasing dead ends for some time...any help is greatly appreciated.

**Server:**
AuthenticAMD, Quad-Core AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 2352, RAM 16GB

Linux 2.6.27 64-bit, Centos 5.5

Plesk 9.5.4, MySQL 5.1.48, PHP 5.2.17

Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) DAV/2 mod_jk/1.2.15 mod_ssl/2.2.3 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 PHP/5.2.17 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.8.8

Tomcat6-6.0.29-1.jpp5, Tomcat-native-1.1.20-1.el5, Apache Solr

**top**

```
17595 apache    20   0 1825m 507m  10m R 100.4  3.2   0:17.50 httpd
17596 apache    20   0 1565m 247m 9936 R 83.1  1.5   0:10.86 httpd
17598 apache    20   0 1430m 110m 6472 S 54.5  0.7   0:08.66 httpd
17599 apache    20   0 1438m 124m  12m S 37.2  0.8   0:11.20 httpd
16197 mysql     20   0 13.0g 2.0g 5440 S  9.6 12.6 297:12.79 mysqld
17617 root      20   0 12748 1172  812 R  0.7  0.0   0:00.88 top
8169 tomcat    20   0 4613m 268m 6056 S  0.3  1.7   6:40.56 java
```

**httpd error_log**

```
[debug] prefork.c(991): AcceptMutex: sysvsem (default: sysvsem)
[info] mod_fcgid: Process manager 17593 started
[debug] proxy_util.c(1854): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 17594 for worker proxy:reverse
[debug] proxy_util.c(1967): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 17594 for (*)
[debug] proxy_util.c(1854): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 17595 for worker proxy:reverse
[debug] proxy_util.c(1873): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized

[notice] child pid 22782 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

[error] (43)Identifier removed: apr_global_mutex_lock(jk_log_lock) failed
[debug] util_ldap.c(2021): LDAP merging Shared Cache conf: shm=0x7fd29a5478c0 rmm=0x7fd29a547918 for VHOST: example.com
[info] APR LDAP: Built with OpenLDAP LDAP SDK
[info] LDAP: SSL support available
[info] Init: Seeding PRNG with 256 bytes of entropy
[info] Init: Generating temporary RSA private keys (512/1024 bits)
[info] Init: Generating temporary DH parameters (512/1024 bits)
[debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(374): shmcb_init allocated 512000 bytes of shared memory
[debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(554): entered shmcb_init_memory()
[debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(576): for 512000 bytes, recommending 4265 indexes
[debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(619): shmcb_init_memory choices follow
[debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(621): division_mask = 0x1F
[debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(623): division_offset = 96
[debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(625): division_size = 15997
[debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(627): queue_size = 2136
[debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(629): index_num = 133
[debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(631): index_offset = 8
[debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(633): index_size = 16
[debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(635): cache_data_offset = 8
[debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(637): cache_data_size = 13853
[debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(650): leaving shmcb_init_memory()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding %P (and %D) to your log files - then you should be able to correlate what you see in 'top' with your acess log.

Answer (score 0):

I see mod_perl in the list. Is this site an application written in PERL? If so, then poorly written PERL code will be at the root of the issue.

Same comment applies to PHP. PHP applications are not known for performance and CMS applications have a reputation as resource hogs. If you are a hosting provider it would be best to either ban this CMS package or charge a higher rate to cover the extra resources.

But, if you are running this CMS for your own use, since it is opensource, you should post another question on StackOverflow, naming the package and asking how to track down and fix the poorly written code.

Comment: Hello Michael, the application is an open source CMS written in PHP and I am not aware of any custom PERL code used in this application.

Comment: KHWeb: CMS applications are pretty heavy by nature. What CMS you have installed and do you have any custom modules installed to it? For example, a 3rd party RSS subscriber statistics module in Drupal did a SELECT COUNT(*) SQL query during every page load and that made everything sloooowww ... in the same manner some component in your CMS can make it very taxing to CPU. If everything else fails, profile the code with XDebug and KCachegrind or some other utils.

Answer (score 0):

> [notice] child pid 22782 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

Something is definitely wrong here, you should add `ulimit -c unlimited` to the beginning of `/etc/init.d/httpd` to get a coredump next time it fails with segfault. Probably mod_jk is a root of the problem since there is an error related to mod_jk in the log.

Comment: Hello Alex, I've added the ulimit and will report back as soon as I have a coredum for the segfault. Thanks!

Comment: I've been monitoring it since yesterday and I am not getting the segmentation fault error or the mod_jk errors. What I am getting this though `code`debug] util_ldap.c(2021): LDAP merging Shared Cache conf:`code`  and also `code`ssl_scache_shmcb.c `code`

Answer (score -1):

I have not seen the segmentation fault error again, but I am still seeing the high CPU coming from httpd. I was able to run a strace on the httpd process with the CPU and I got following:

```
   # strace -c -p 28964
    Process 28964 attached - interrupt to quit
    ^CProcess 28964 detached
    % time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
    ------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
     88.94    0.006093           0     98299      4562 lstat
      3.01    0.000206           0      2740           getcwd
      2.28    0.000156           0      2158         2 read
      2.26    0.000155           0       541        37 open
      1.68    0.000115           0      1321      1321 readlink
      1.52    0.000104           0      1678       822 access
      0.32    0.000022           0       502           fstat
      0.00    0.000000           0        25           write
      0.00    0.000000           0       507           close
      0.00    0.000000           0       547       478 stat
      0.00    0.000000           0        23           poll
      0.00    0.000000           0         2           rt_sigaction
      0.00    0.000000           0         2           rt_sigprocmask
      0.00    0.000000           0         2           writev
      0.00    0.000000           0         3           setitimer
      0.00    0.000000           0         1           sendfile
 ...
    ------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
    100.00    0.006851                108381      7224 total
```

The 4562 errors from lstat are the same type of errors and show up like this on the log file:

```
# strace -f -t -o /var/log/strace.output -p 28964
```

strace.output

```
28964 07:10:38 lstat("/var", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
28964 07:10:38 lstat("/var/www", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=94, ...}) = 0
28964 07:10:38 lstat("/var/www/vhosts", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
28964 07:10:38 lstat("/var/www/vhosts/example.com", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
28964 07:10:38 lstat("/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
28964 07:10:38 lstat("/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=30, ...}) = 0
28964 07:10:38 lstat("/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=66, ...}) = 0
28964 07:10:38 lstat("/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
28964 07:10:38 lstat("/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/views", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
28964 07:10:38 lstat("/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/views/includes", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
28964 07:10:38 lstat("/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/views/includes/sites", 0x7fff1e627370) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

The folders listed above are all in this website directory and part of the Drupal CMS. However  the last one listed

```
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/views/includes/sites
```

does not exists and it should really be

```
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites
```

which does exist. Looks like lstat is trying to read a directory that does not exists....?

```
-1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

What would be the best way to troubleshoot this and find the source of this error for the missing directory?

Comment: What is the PHP log telling you, and what Drupal modules are running?

Comment: Hello Ben, The PHP log has a few errors but it looks like they don't correlate to the time I see this high cpu (I see this high cpu when I browse any page on this site). There are about 270 modules running on this site.